# If $V={v_{1},v_{2},...,v_{n}}$ is an orthogonal set, determine if $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left\| v_{i} \right\|=\left\| \sum_{i=1}^{n}v_{i} \right\|$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, orthogonality, triangle-inequality

If $V=\{v_{1},v_{2},...,v_{n}\}$ is an orthogonal set, determine if $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left\| v_{i} \right\|=\left\| \sum_{i=1}^{n}v_{i} \right\|$ is true or not.

I don´t even know where to start. However, before trying to solve this one, I solved the following:

Prove that: $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left\| v_{i} \right\|\le \left\| \sum_{i=1}^{n}v_{i} \right\|$$
I proved it using triangle inequality and induction. Are this two connected in some way? Can you solve the first one using the second one?

Comment: It's not true. Try finding counterexamples. No need to be fancy: you could even stick to two orthogonal vectors in $\Bbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Try $(1,-1)$ and $(1,1)$; they are orthogonal. Are the two sides equal?

Comment: Use the Pythagorean theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem#Inner_product_spaces to transform the right handside and derive that it is true iff at most one $v_i$ is $\ne0$.